# Building a query for a table whose fields From and To are placed in reversible columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like this:

```
Journey  HHMM   Chkpt1  Chkpt2
41   1600   AAA BBB 
41   1601   AAA BBB
41   1602   AAA BBB
41   1603   CCC DDD
41   1603   BBB CCC
41   1604   DDD EEE
```

The points Chkpt1 and Chkpt2 define a segment from a road.
In this case, the vehicle that did journey 41 passed by these segments: AAA-BBB, BBB-CCC, CCC-DDD, DDD-EEE.

My question:
I need to get the first and last points from the journey, and their respective times.
In this case, the answer is AAA (1600) and EEE (1604).

There are some points to be considered to get this answer:

1) the trajectory is tracked at each minute. This can generate multiple lines with the same checkpoints.

2) every segment is tracked. If the vehicle moves from a segment to other during a same minute, more than a line can be inserted at the same minute - and, for some reasons of  implementation, they may appear not in chronological order.

3) the trickiest point - the vehicle in not necessarily moving from Chkpt1 to Chkpt2. It may be moving from Chkpt2 to Chkpt1. The question is how to deduce the real direction (there´s not a  Direction column on this table and the table must not be changed).

For example:

```
Journey HHMM    Chkpt1  Chkpt2 
42  1700    YYY ZZZ 
42  1701    YYY ZZZ 
42  1702    WWW XXX 
42  1702    XXX YYY 
42  1702    VVV WWW 
42  1703    UUU VVV
```

In this case, the vehicle is moving from ZZZ to UUU and the answer is ZZZ (1700) / UUU (1703).

In each segment, it comes from Chkpt2 to Chkpt1.
During a same journey, all the lines must be tracked with the same direction.

For journey 41, all movements are from Chkpt1 to Chkpt2. We get the trajectory comparing Chkpt2 (1602) to Chkpt1 (1603), so we see the vehicle moved from AAA-BBB to BBB-CCC, and so on.

For journey 42, all movements are from Chkpt2 to Chkpt1. We get the trajectory comparing Chkpt1 (1700) to Chkpt2 (1702), so we see the vehicle moved from ZZZ-YYY to YYY-XXX, and so on.

Desired results would be:

```
Journey ChkptStart  Time1   ChkptEnd    Time2 
41  AAA 1600    EEE 1604 
42  ZZZ 1700    UUU 1703
```

Well, I don´t have enough experience with SQL for a complex query as this.

Can anyone give me a help about this problem ?

Comment: Can you show your desired results?

Comment: Are you allowed to use PL/SQL? Does it have to be done in one SQL query?

Comment: @EmersonYassunaga please edit your post and show the desired results there.

Comment: @Bobby Durrett: we don´t use PL/SQL. At this company, with the tools we´ve been using, everything is being implemented with one SQL query. Sometimes these queries get very large or not simple to understand.

Comment: ...this is probably going to be a nasty query.  This would be far easier if we had a `(timestamp, checkpoint)` relationship, instead (and likely in better resolution); timeseries data is usually better as the capture of state, not the transitions.  Or at least making it so that the checkpoints were an explicit `(start, end)` pair (instead of, presumably, sorted).  If `not appear in chronological order` you mean "the rows in the database aren't ordered", that's expected.  If you mean "the rows might have the wrong timestamp", you're going to fail on something, period.

Comment: Is this your only data?  This looks more like something you'd get after first-step analysis.  I'd normally assume `(timestamp, checkpoint)` would be the initial dataset.  Other questions: are segments ever revisited, or the track traversed backwards?  What (known) pathological cases are there?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: I mean "the rows aren´t ordered" - in the example, "CCC DDD" comes before "BBB CCC". This doesn´t alllow me to compare Chkpt2 from row N with Chkpt1 from row N+1.

Comment: @EmersonYassunaga - Yeah, that's expected: databases don't have a sense of "order" for tables.  The "order" is dependent on your data (in this, time series or point series)

Comment: What about table2 says we end at `uuu` and start at `zzz`? What's the factor that determines this logic?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: no other pathogical cases, I think ... no segments revisited and no backwards movements.

Comment: @Simon: this logic was built many years ago, for business reasons, and can´t be changed, unfortunately. There are two kinds of segments, single- and multi-directional. It seems that bi-directional segments are always represented as "YYY-ZZZ", even if the vehicle goes from ZZZ to YYY. At 17:00-17:01 we see it´s moving on YYY-ZZZ segment. At 17:02 we see it on XXX-YYY segment. So we deduce it is going from ZZZ to YYY, then passed from YYY to XXX.

Comment: Do you think you can use the with clause in your SQL? Might make it less messy. What version of Oracle are you working with?

Comment: @Bobby: with is allowed. Using Oracle SQL Developer 1.5.5.

Comment: `WITH` nothing, you need a pair of recursive queries for this.  @Emerson - note that one minor pathological case is if there's two segments in the earliest timestamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, it's a doozy (although not as bad as I first thought):

```
WITH Deduplicated AS (SELECT id, checkpoint1, checkpoint2, MIN(hhmm) as startTime, MAX(hhmm) as endTime
                      FROM Journey
                      GROUP BY id, checkpoint1, checkpoint2),
     Path (id, originPoint, originStartTime, originEndTime, checkpoint2, startTime, endTime, lev)
          AS (SELECT id, checkpoint1, startTime, endTime, checkpoint2, startTime, endTime, 0
              FROM Deduplicated
              WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                FROM Journey b
                                WHERE b.id = Deduplicated.id
                                      AND b.checkpoint2 = Deduplicated.checkpoint1)
              UNION ALL
              SELECT Path.id, Path.originPoint, Path.originStartTime, Path.originEndTime,
                     Deduplicated.checkpoint2, Deduplicated.startTime, Deduplicated.endTime, lev + 1
              FROM Path
              JOIN Deduplicated
                ON Deduplicated.id = Path.id
                   AND Deduplicated.checkpoint1 = Path.checkpoint2)
SELECT id, 
       CASE WHEN originStartTime > startTime 
                 OR originEndTime > endTime
            THEN checkPoint2
            ELSE originPoint END AS checkpointStart, 
       LEAST(originStartTime, startTime) AS time1,
       CASE WHEN originStartTime > startTime 
                 OR originEndTime > endTime
            THEN originPoint
            ELSE checkPoint2 END AS checkpointEnd, 
       GREATEST(originEndTime, endTime) AS endTime
FROM (SELECT Path.*, MAX(lev) OVER(PARTITION BY id) AS lim
      FROM Path) Filtered
WHERE lev = lim
```

<kbd>[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/86f06/7/0)</kbd>

Passes the mild pathological case where there are multiple "starting time" segments.  Essentially, the best way is to ignore the time until after completing the recursive graph (which succeeds), then check to see if the direction of the timestamps matches the recursive direction.

Comment: It didn't produce the desired result when I ran it.  Got 1701 for ZZZ instead of 1700.

Comment: @BobbyDurrett - fixed that, kicking myself that I didn't notice.

Comment: Hello ! Only now I see the solutions you presented, many thanks.

Comment: I still need to test your code, and due to the Holiday I probably won´t do it until next week. Anyway, you´ve already tested it and, clearly, both of you did a nice job. I´m going to register my vote as soon I discover how.

Comment: And I register my deception for being able to place only one vote.

Comment: I posted a new version of my solution fyi.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: just to confirm, I adapted your solution to my case and that worked fine !! Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

New version to handle some of the issues discussed in the comments:

```
with 
-- to_minutes takes the rows in test and changes their HHMM time format 
-- to minutes. This makes it easier to compare rows to see if they are 
-- 1 minute before or after each other.
to_minutes as
(
select 
journey,
(trunc(hhmm/100)*60)+hhmm-(trunc(hhmm/100)*100) mins,
chkpt1,
chkpt2
from 
test
),
-- before_same lists rows that have a row that has the same values for
-- chkpt1 and chkpt2 and is from the previous minute.
before_same as
(
select 
this_row.journey,
this_row.mins,
this_row.chkpt1,
this_row.chkpt2
from
to_minutes this_row,
to_minutes prev_row
where
this_row.journey = prev_row.journey and
this_row.mins = prev_row.mins+1 and
this_row.chkpt1 = prev_row.chkpt1 and
this_row.chkpt2 = prev_row.chkpt2
),
-- after_same lists rows that have a row that has the same values for
-- chkpt1 and chkpt2 and is from the next minute.
after_same as
(
select 
this_row.journey,
this_row.mins,
this_row.chkpt1,
this_row.chkpt2
from
to_minutes this_row,
to_minutes next_row
where
this_row.journey = next_row.journey and
this_row.mins+1 = next_row.mins and
this_row.chkpt1 = next_row.chkpt1 and
this_row.chkpt2 = next_row.chkpt2
),
-- At this point the subqueries are working on chains that go from
-- left to right which means that chkpt1 is the start of the chain or path.
--
-- lr_before_diff lists rows that have a row from the previous minute or the same minute
-- with chkpt2 of that row = chkpt1 of this row.
lr_before_diff as
(
select 
this_row.journey,
this_row.mins,
this_row.chkpt1,
this_row.chkpt2
from
to_minutes this_row,
to_minutes prev_row
where
this_row.journey = prev_row.journey and
(this_row.mins = prev_row.mins+1 or
this_row.mins = prev_row.mins) and
this_row.chkpt1 = prev_row.chkpt2
),
-- lr_after_diff lists rows that have a row from the next minute or the same minute
-- with chkpt1 of that row = chkpt2 of this row.
lr_after_diff as
(
select 
this_row.journey,
this_row.mins,
this_row.chkpt1,
this_row.chkpt2
from
to_minutes this_row,
to_minutes next_row
where
this_row.journey = next_row.journey and
(this_row.mins+1 = next_row.mins or
this_row.mins = next_row.mins) and
this_row.chkpt2 = next_row.chkpt1
),
-- lr_begin lists the rows that do not have a row before
-- them so they could be start rows for a lr path
lr_begin as
(
select * from to_minutes
minus
(select * from before_same
union
select * from lr_before_diff)
),
-- lr_end lists the rows that do not have a row after
-- them so they could be end rows for a lr path
lr_end as
(
select * from to_minutes
minus
(select * from after_same
union
select * from lr_after_diff)
),
-- lr_beg_count lists number of beginning rows for each journey
-- should be 1 for a lr path
lr_beg_count as
(
select journey,count(*) cnt
from lr_begin
group by journey
),
-- lr_end_count lists number of ending rows for each journey
-- should be 1 for a lr path
lr_end_count as
(
select journey,count(*) cnt
from lr_end
group by journey
),
-- lr_journeys lists the journey numbers of the lr paths
-- only journeys with 1 begin and end row are lr paths
lr_journeys as
(
select lr_beg_count.journey
from lr_beg_count,lr_end_count
where
lr_beg_count.journey = lr_end_count.journey and
lr_beg_count.cnt = 1 and
lr_end_count.cnt = 1
),
-- lr_journey_detail combines the begin and end rows into 
-- one row
lr_journey_detail as
(
select
lr_begin.journey,
lr_begin.chkpt1 start_checkpoint,
lr_begin.mins start_mins,
lr_end.chkpt2 end_checkpoint,
lr_end.mins end_mins
from
lr_begin,
lr_end,
lr_journeys
where
lr_begin.journey=lr_end.journey and
lr_journeys.journey=lr_end.journey
),
-- now do the same for right to left paths
rl_before_diff as
(
select 
this_row.journey,
this_row.mins,
this_row.chkpt1,
this_row.chkpt2
from
to_minutes this_row,
to_minutes prev_row
where
this_row.journey = prev_row.journey and
(this_row.mins = prev_row.mins+1 or
this_row.mins = prev_row.mins) and
this_row.chkpt2 = prev_row.chkpt1
),
rl_after_diff as
(
select 
this_row.journey,
this_row.mins,
this_row.chkpt1,
this_row.chkpt2
from
to_minutes this_row,
to_minutes next_row
where
this_row.journey = next_row.journey and
(this_row.mins+1 = next_row.mins or
this_row.mins = next_row.mins) and
this_row.chkpt1 = next_row.chkpt2
),
rl_begin as
(
select * from to_minutes
minus
(select * from before_same
union
select * from rl_before_diff)
),
rl_end as
(
select * from to_minutes
minus
(select * from after_same
union
select * from rl_after_diff)
),
rl_beg_count as
(
select journey,count(*) cnt
from rl_begin
group by journey
),
rl_end_count as
(
select journey,count(*) cnt
from rl_end
group by journey
),
rl_journeys as
(
select rl_beg_count.journey
from rl_beg_count,rl_end_count
where
rl_beg_count.journey = rl_end_count.journey and
rl_beg_count.cnt = 1 and
rl_end_count.cnt = 1
),
rl_journey_detail as
(
select
rl_begin.journey,
rl_begin.chkpt2 start_checkpoint,
rl_begin.mins start_mins,
rl_end.chkpt1 end_checkpoint,
rl_end.mins end_mins
from
rl_begin,
rl_end,
rl_journeys
where
rl_begin.journey=rl_end.journey and
rl_journeys.journey=rl_end.journey
),
-- now combine the two journey detail rows
journey_detail as
(
select * from lr_journey_detail 
union
select * from rl_journey_detail 
where journey not in
(select journey from lr_journey_detail)
),
-- convert back to hhmm
convert_hhmm as
(
select
journey,
start_checkpoint,
(trunc(start_mins/60)*100) + start_mins - (trunc(start_mins/60)*60) start_hhmm,
end_checkpoint,
(trunc(end_mins/60)*100) + end_mins - (trunc(end_mins/60)*60) end_hhmm
from journey_detail
)
select * from convert_hhmm 
order by journey;
```

Output from test data:

```
   JOURNEY STA START_HHMM END   END_HHMM
---------- --- ---------- --- ----------
        41 AAA       1600 EEE       1604
        42 ZZZ       1700 UUU       1703
```

Maybe a better solution using hierarchical queries.
https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/Hierarchical-Queries.htm#SQLRF52332

```
with 
-- to_minutes takes the rows in test and changes their HHMM time format 
-- to minutes. This makes it easier to compare rows to see if they are 
-- 1 minute before or after each other.
to_minutes as
(
select 
journey,
(trunc(hhmm/100)*60)+hhmm-(trunc(hhmm/100)*100) mins,
chkpt1,
chkpt2
from 
test
),
-- min_max_cnt finds the min and max minute numbers for each journey
-- also counts number of rows in journey
min_max_cnt as
(
select 
journey,
min(mins) min_mins,
max(mins) max_mins,
count(*) cnt
from to_minutes
group by journey
),
lr_paths as
(
select
journey,
chkpt1,
chkpt2,
mins,
level lvl,
SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(to_char(mins)||'-'||chkpt1||'-'||chkpt2, '/') path
from to_minutes a
start with a.mins =
(select m.min_mins
from min_max_cnt m
where
a.journey = m.journey)
connect by
(
(prior mins + 1 = mins and
prior journey = journey and
prior chkpt1 = chkpt1 and
prior chkpt2 = chkpt2) or
((prior mins + 1 = mins or 
  prior mins = mins)
and
prior journey = journey and
prior chkpt2 = chkpt1)
)),
max_level_lr as
(
select journey,max(lvl) max_lvl
from lr_paths
group by journey
),
longest_lr_paths as 
(
select 
l.journey,
l.chkpt1,
l.chkpt2,
l.mins,
l.lvl,
l.path
from lr_paths l,max_level_lr m
where
l.journey = m.journey and
l.lvl = m.max_lvl
),
extract_lr as
(
select
journey,
substr(substr(path,instr(path,'-',1,1)+1,instr(path,'-',1,2)-instr(path,'-',1,1)-1),1,3) start_checkpoint,
substr(substr(path,2,instr(path,'-',1,1)-2),1,4) start_mins,
substr(substr(path,instr(path,'-',-1,1)+1,3),1,3) end_checkpoint,
substr(substr(path,instr(path,'/',-1,1)+1,instr(path,'-',-1,2)-instr(path,'/',-1,1)-1),1,4) end_mins,
lvl path_length
from 
longest_lr_paths
),
lr_full_path as
(
select
e.journey,
e.start_checkpoint,
e.start_mins,
e.end_checkpoint,
e.end_mins
from 
extract_lr e,
min_max_cnt m
where 
e.journey = m.journey and
e.path_length = m.cnt
),
rl_paths as
(
select
journey,
chkpt1,
chkpt2,
mins,
level lvl,
SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(to_char(mins)||'-'||chkpt1||'-'||chkpt2, '/') path
from to_minutes a
start with a.mins =
(select m.min_mins
from min_max_cnt m
where
a.journey = m.journey)
connect by
(
(prior mins + 1 = mins and
prior journey = journey and
prior chkpt1 = chkpt1 and
prior chkpt2 = chkpt2) or
((prior mins + 1 = mins or 
  prior mins = mins)
and
prior journey = journey and
prior chkpt1 = chkpt2)
)),
max_level_rl as
(
select journey,max(lvl) max_lvl
from rl_paths
group by journey
),
longest_rl_paths as 
(
select 
l.journey,
l.chkpt1,
l.chkpt2,
l.mins,
l.lvl,
l.path
from rl_paths l,max_level_rl m
where
l.journey = m.journey and
l.lvl = m.max_lvl
),
extract_rl as
(
select
journey,
substr(substr(path,instr(path,'-',1,2)+1,3),1,3) start_checkpoint,
substr(substr(path,2,instr(path,'-',1,1)-2),1,4) start_mins,
substr(substr(path,instr(path,'-',-1,2)+1,3),1,3) end_checkpoint,
substr(substr(path,instr(path,'/',-1,1)+1,instr(path,'-',-1,2)-instr(path,'/',-1,1)-1),1,4) end_mins,
lvl path_length
from 
longest_rl_paths
),
rl_full_path as
(
select
e.journey,
e.start_checkpoint,
e.start_mins,
e.end_checkpoint,
e.end_mins
from 
extract_rl e,
min_max_cnt m
where 
e.journey = m.journey and
e.path_length = m.cnt
),
all_paths as
(
select * from lr_full_path 
union
select * from rl_full_path 
where journey not in
(select journey from lr_full_path)
),
convert_hhmm as
(
select
journey,
start_checkpoint,
(trunc(start_mins/60)*100) + start_mins - (trunc(start_mins/60)*60) start_hhmm,
end_checkpoint,
(trunc(end_mins/60)*100) + end_mins - (trunc(end_mins/60)*60) end_hhmm
from all_paths
)
select * from convert_hhmm 
order by
journey;
```

Comment: Fails completely if either the start or the end has multiple segments at the same time.  Also, please don't use the implicit-join (comma-separated `FROM` clause) syntax: always explicitly list your joins, and put as many conditions as possible into the attendant `ON` clauses.  Reserve the `WHERE` clause for conditions that only touch the single table in the `FROM` clause (and a few other special tricks, not germane here)

Comment: I couldn't get it to fail by adding extra segments to the front or back. Seems to work with multiple segments. Can you post sample data that it fails on?

Comment: Old habits die hard on the join syntax. Been doing joins using Oracle's syntax for 23+ years. But, I know the ANSI syntax has a number of advantages. Had to learn it for the Oracle 9i OCP certification but most of the code that I support doesn't use it and I'm more comfortable with Oracle syntax. But, it is good to encourage the ANSI standard.

Comment: Sure, [the data I used for my query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8bfe4d/1/0) causes it to fail pretty spectacularly.  Case 48 seems to be generating a full cartesian join.

Comment: Thanks. It definitely does not handle the case with multiple segments at the beginning or end.

Comment: I redid my solution. Not sure if it is better than the other answer since it is much longer. But, it is probably the way I would resolve the situation.

Comment: @BobbyDurrett: thank you, and I hope to find some time to test your new solution.

Comment: Bobby: I did a quick test and found 3 diferences between your results and CM´s.

Comment: Most of them are because I didn´t tell some details of my real database. 1) You only show 3 characters in the start_checkpoint and end_checkpoint. But that seems ok, since I didn´t mention that the length of the string could be greater.

Comment: The other point is that my timestamp is too different from the example I showed - and the date also should be considered (sorry !) "2017 Nov 13, 17:00" is recorder as a number, not "1700" but "201711131700". Of course, this should present different results in the case the 2nd checkpoint is reached after midnight - but I saw these two effects: 2) START_HHMM and END_HHMM have always the same value 3337 at every row. 3) your listing show only 52 lines, while CM´s shows 231. I haven´t studied these questions yet, but very likely I did some fault while adapting your code.

Comment: Ok. I had fun playing with it whatever happens. I hope it is useful to you. Let me know if you are still looking for a solution.