# Fields From and To placed in reversible columns which change anytime

Tags: sql, oracle

This is my table Journey:

Case 1: always moving from Chkpt1 to Chkpt2

```
Journey  HHMM   Chkpt1  Chkpt2
41   1600   AAA BBB 
41   1601   AAA BBB
41   1602   AAA BBB
41   1603   CCC DDD
41   1603   BBB CCC
41   1604   DDD EEE
```

The points Chkpt1 and Chkpt2 define a segment from a road. In this case, a vehicle did its journey 41 passing by these segments: AAA-BBB, BBB-CCC, CCC-DDD, DDD-EEE.

My question: I need to get the first and last points from the journey, and their respective times. For this case 1, the answer is:

```
Journey ChkptStart  Time1   ChkptEnd    Time2 
41  AAA 1600    EEE 1604
```

There are some points to be considered to get this answer:

1) the trajectory is tracked at each minute. This can generate multiple lines with the same checkpoints.

2) every segment is tracked. If the vehicle moves from a segment to other during a same minute, more than a line can be inserted at the same minute - they may appear in any order (CCC-DDD appears before BBB-CCC).

3) the trickiest point - at each line, the vehicle in not necessarily moving from Chkpt1 to Chkpt2. It may be moving from Chkpt2 to Chkpt1. The question is how to deduce the real direction (there´s not a Direction column on this table and the table must not be changed).

Case 2: always moving from Chkpt2 to Chkpt1

```
Journey HHMM    Chkpt1  Chkpt2 
42  1700    YYY ZZZ 
42  1701    YYY ZZZ 
42  1702    WWW XXX 
42  1702    XXX YYY 
42  1702    VVV WWW 
42  1703    UUU VVV 

In this case, the vehicle is moving from ZZZ to UUU and the answer is 

Journey ChkptStart  Time1   ChkptEnd    Time2 
42  ZZZ 1700    UUU 1703
```

Case 3: combining movements from Chkpt1 to Chkpt2 and from Chkpt2 to Chkpt1

```
Journey  HHMM   Chkpt1  Chkpt2
43   2100   PPP QQQ 
43   2101   PPP QQQ
43   2102   PPP QQQ
43   2103   SSS RRR
43   2103   QQQ RRR
43   2104   SSS TTT
```

That means: 
From 21:00 to 21:02 the vehicle goes to PPP to QQQ (Chkpt1 to Chkpt2). 
At   21:03, it goes to QQQ to RRR (Chkpt1 to Chkpt2). 
At   21:03, it goes to RRR to SSS (Chkpt2 to Chkpt1). 
At   21:04, it goes to SSS to TTT (Chkpt1 to Chkpt2).

So, we don´t have anymore that restriction that a car is always going from Chkpt1 to Chkpt2, or always going from Chkpt2 to Chkpt1. This can change from one segment to the next.

Desired result:

```
Journey ChkptStart  Time1   ChkptEnd    Time2 
43  PPP 2100    TTT 2104
```

A segment is always represented by the same order. A segment once represented as WWW-XXX can´t be represented by XXX-WWW later.

I have been using the solution below (presented by Clockwork-Muse).
This was a great solution for my original question ([Building a query for a table whose fields From and To are placed in reversible columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46982564/building-a-query-for-a-table-whose-fields-from-and-to-are-placed-in-reversible-c/46984752#46984752)), covering the cases 1 and 2.

```
WITH Deduplicated AS (SELECT id, checkpoint1, checkpoint2, MIN(hhmm) as startTime, MAX(hhmm) as endTime
                      FROM Journey
                      GROUP BY id, checkpoint1, checkpoint2),
     Path (id, originPoint, originStartTime, originEndTime, checkpoint2, startTime, endTime, lev)
          AS (SELECT id, checkpoint1, startTime, endTime, checkpoint2, startTime, endTime, 0
              FROM Deduplicated
              WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                FROM Journey b
                                WHERE b.id = Deduplicated.id
                                      AND b.checkpoint2 = Deduplicated.checkpoint1)
              UNION ALL
              SELECT Path.id, Path.originPoint, Path.originStartTime, Path.originEndTime,
                     Deduplicated.checkpoint2, Deduplicated.startTime, Deduplicated.endTime, lev + 1
              FROM Path
              JOIN Deduplicated
                ON Deduplicated.id = Path.id
                   AND Deduplicated.checkpoint1 = Path.checkpoint2)
SELECT id, 
       CASE WHEN originStartTime > startTime 
                 OR originEndTime > endTime
            THEN checkPoint2
            ELSE originPoint END AS checkpointStart, 
       LEAST(originStartTime, startTime) AS time1,
       CASE WHEN originStartTime > startTime 
                 OR originEndTime > endTime
            THEN originPoint
            ELSE checkPoint2 END AS checkpointEnd, 
       GREATEST(originEndTime, endTime) AS endTime
FROM (SELECT Path.*, MAX(lev) OVER(PARTITION BY id) AS lim
      FROM Path) Filtered
WHERE lev = lim
```

Question One:

Now I need to have it adapted for the Case 3. How could this be done ?

Question Two:

Journeys with just one segment are not being returned by this query. For example:

```
Journey  HHMM   Chkpt1  Chkpt2
45   0900   RRR SSS 
45   0901   RRR SSS
45   0902   RRR SSS
```

Desired result:

```
Journey ChkptStart  Time1   ChkptEnd    Time2 
45  RRR 0900    SSS 0902
```

It seems that the query needs at least two segments, so it can establish a connection from the first to the second segment. In fact, with a single record, we can´t determine which are the start and the end points.

In this case, we can consider that the car is moving to Chkpt1 to Chkpt2.
How should the query be changed to do this ? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem as stated cannot be solved. The main reason is that the times may be equal. Imagine you have just two rows, and both have HHMM = 1600. The checkpoint pairs are (AAA, BBB) and (BBB, CCC). From this data, you can't tell if the vehicle moved from AAA to BBB and then to CCC, or from CCC to BBB and then to AAA. What would make more sense would be for the HHMM column to be  a START_TS instead (start timestamp). These would be unique. So the direction of the first leg of the trip can be inferred from the endpoints of the second leg (assuming there are no cycles in the trip).

Comment: Also, I just looked at your other question. I didn't read the "correct" answer, nor did I try to test it, but I don't see how it can solve the case I just described in the Comment above this one.

Comment: The earlier answer also doesn't cover the case where you cover the same segment twice, but with something in between, as the deduplicated CTE will see one segment that skips over the part in the middle. As @mathguy says, there are some problems that are not solvable, even though you may come up with something that *mostly* works.

Comment: @mathguy: you´re right ! In this case, the problem could not be solved. So I´d like to add this condition: in the first minute, there´s only one record, so it´s always possible to distinguish which segment is the first.

Comment: @TomC: in fact. Another condition would be: no segment covered twice at a same journey. Thanks.

Comment: You still need to add "... and there are no cycles in my journey."  Without that, it is not enough for the FIRST minute to have a unique segment. Imagine this input data: 1600 has just (AAA, BBB). 1601 has (BBB, CCC) and (CCC, AAA). You can't tell, from this data (and knowing that "direction" is not part of the data, and neither is "which of the two segments at 1601 was traveled first) you can't tell if the journey was AAA to BBB, and then BBB to CCC to AAA, or if the first leg was BBB to AAA, and then in the second minute AAA to BBB to CCC.

Comment: Your additional condition will ONLY help if there can be no cycles in the journey. For an even simpler example: 1600 shows (AAA, BBB) only, and 1601 shows (BBB, AAA) only. Which was the direction in the first minute, and which in the second? And if the first leg took one minute and ten seconds, then you have (AAA, BBB) at 1600 and (AAA, BBB) and (BBB, AAA) at 1601, and you still can't tell which was the direction in the first minute.

Comment: @mathguy: you´re right about these cycles. I just say that in the particular case of the problem I´m dealing with, there´s no need to worry about it (at least by now).

Comment: Well, I studied this original query and my conclusion is that this will not be simple to adapt it to the new requirement. There´s a simpler way to get this result interchanging the two columns when necessary. I´m going to open a new question about it.